# Magento FPC with Redis - Header not punched out

Tags: full-page-cache, ee-1.14

Redis: 2.8.19

I have punched a hole in the header and FPC is enabled. Everything works great with file based cache. However as soon as I switch to Redis as cache backend, the header on cart and account pages are cached (not changing based on user). The content updates but not the header.
The site is not open i.e. only logged in customers can access the site.

**cache.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <placeholders>
        <header_cache>
            <block>page/html_header</block>
            <name>header</name>
            <placeholder>MODULENAME_HEADER</placeholder>
            <container>Company_Module_Model_Container_Header</container>
            <cache_lifetime>0</cache_lifetime>
        </header_cache>
    </placeholders>
</config>
```

**Company/Module/Model/Container/Header.php**

```
<?php
class Company_Module_Model_Container_Header extends Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Container_Abstract
{
    protected function _getIdentifier()
    {
        $cacheId = $this->_getCookieValue(Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Cookie::COOKIE_CUSTOMER, '')
            . '_'
            . $this->_getCookieValue(Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Cookie::COOKIE_CUSTOMER_LOGGED_IN, '');
        return $cacheId;
    }

    /**
     * Get cache identifier
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getCacheId()
    {
        return 'CONTAINER_HEADER_' . md5($this->_placeholder->getAttribute('cache_id') . $this->_getIdentifier());
    }

    /**
     * Render block content
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _renderBlock()
    {
        $layout = $this->_getLayout('default');
        $block = $layout->getBlock('header');
        $block->setSkipRenderTag(true);
        return $block->toHtml();

    }


    protected function _saveCache($data, $id, $tags = array(), $lifetime = null) { return false; }    

}
```

It's very strange that everything works fine on file based caching. 
With Redis, all pages (category, product view, cms pages) punch the hole just fine. It's just the cart and account pages.
Can anyone please help me or point me in the right direction?